# How to make fixed position child element outside the section from fixed position parent

Tags: css

I have created a Filter section with a fixed position inside that  Filter button included and this button also fixed position, but I'm facing an issue is wants to show filter button outside the filter section.

```css
.filter-component .filter-panel {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 22%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #254260;
 color: white;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 200px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 200px;
    overflow: scroll;  
}
.filter-component .filter-panel .filter-btn {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 4;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.filter-component .filter-panel .filter-btn button {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 0;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.filter-component .filter-panel .panel-heading{
padding: 10px 15px;
background : #142f4b;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-component" id="sidebar">
<div class="filter-panel " role="tablist">
 <div class="filter-btn">
  <button>Show Filter</button>  
 </div> 
 <div class="panel-heading" role="tab"><div class="panel-title text-white d-flex flex-nowrap align-items-center">Filter Your Search</div></div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: `fixed` is alway related to the `viewport`. I suggest you use `absolute` on the child

Comment: Sir, but I need make filter button should be fixed in left corner of the screen

Comment: Then you can't relate it to the position of the parent. With absolute it will be. *Did you try it?*.

Comment: Sir, Is there any way to make filter button positioned and display in left side of the screen

Comment: Yes, with position fixed **but** the position will be related to the viewport not the parent element. I'm pretty sure making the button div `absolute` will do what you want.